# Passing db path to \l or .Q.l using a variable

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I'm writing a q script that loads a db in a particular path and does some processing on it.  The location of the db is currently hardcoded in the script,  but I want to pass the db path as an argument and get it to load from the path in the variable.

Currently it looks like this:

```
q) \l /path/to/dbDir        #Works
```

I figured out that .Q.l should let us do this using a variable,  so I tried using the following in the script,

```
dbPath:`$.z.x 0
.Q.l hsym dbPath            #Fails
```

When running with argument /path/to/dbDir,  the script always fails with some unreadable stuff and:

```
':/path/to/dbDir: No such file or directory
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.Q.l](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#ql-load) is synonymous with [\l](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#l-load-file-or-directory) which only takes a single argument, which is not an hsym but a file or directory name.

Incidentally the unreadable stuff was the function definition, followed by a type error (as it was not expecting an hsym)

Answer (score 5):

`\x ...` is always equivalent to `system"x ..."`, which is the general solution to the "how do i pass a variable to a `\` command question

in your case, you want

```
system"l ",.z.x 0
```

(btw, i don't think `.Q.l` is involved in `\l` of code, only of data, so don't try to use it to load extra .q files)

Answer (score 2):

Okay,  it seems to work when we try .Q.l without the hsym like this:

```
dbPath:`$.z.x 0
.Q.l dbPath
```